# What's the difference between these stone brick blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my inventory, there are two seemingly identical stone brick blocks.

[image: diggy diggy hole]

The stack of 48 stone bricks was crafted from furnaced stone. The stack of 9 stone bricks was dug from stone brick stairs, which were crafted from stone bricks. The two stacks are identical in name and appearance, except they don't stack with each other. Neither stack is cracked stone brick or mossy stone brick.

What's the difference?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I had an issue yesterday where mining stone brick stairs dropped a mossy stone brick block I couldn't pick up

Comment: If you could upload your level.dat (or just open with an NBT viewer), we can find if they are the same item or not.

Comment: **Note: The bug described in this question no longer exists,** and stone brick stairs now drop as themselves rather than blocks.

Comment: This question should probably not be closed as 'too localized' as per the [meta] post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5282/can-we-stop-closing-questions-that-have-become-obsolete-as-too-localized

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**East-facing stairs break into the second type of plain stone brick, due to a glitch.**

Some blocks hold a data value, to determine things like the hue of wool or the height of wheat. All stairs use a data value of 0-3 to determine which direction they face:

- 0: South
- 1: North
- 2: West
- 3: East

But stone brick uses this data value to determine type:

- 0: Normal
- 1: Mossy
- 2: Cracked
- Anything else: Not normally obtainable, will default to normal

When you smash a stone brick, **it retains its data value**, which is why smashing stairs creates different stone bricks. **The type of brick corresponds to the direction of the stair it came from.** Because there are four cardinal directions and only three types of brick defined, the fourth type of brick just looks like normal brick.

Comment: Neat! This is what makes debugging so much "fun".

Comment: Nice code digging!

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth noting that Stone Brick blocks and Double Stone Brick Slab blocks are functionally identical. It's not impossible that, say, the stone brick stairs are incorrectly converting into Double Stone Brick Slab blocks in  your inventory, but the Double Stone Brick Slab blocks are being reported by the game as Stone Brick blocks mistakenly.

You might try placing one of each, then destroying each in turn. If both blocks drop identical materials, then something stranger is going on.

Comment: Placing one of each, and destroying them, recovers one of each the original sorts of Stone Brick. Both are called "Stone Bricks" in the inventory (as are cracked and mossy stone brick).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's just a bug. Check the MC value. If it's different, nothing will happen.