# What's the data value ID for mossy stone brick and cracked stone brick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do you guy know the ID for those twos ?

[image][image]

Can't find it in the data value JPEG on wiki minecraft ...

Comment: If I were you, I'd start trying numbers starting where the JPEG leaves off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ID for both of them is 98 (decimal), same as the normal Stone Brick. Like different color wool blocks, their appearance is decided by their damage value (98<sup>1</sup> for the Mossy Stone Brick, 98<sup>2</sup> for Cracked Stone Brick).

The Minecraft wiki has an updated [list of data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values).

Comment: I'm using that data sheet too. You can see that the damage value for the Stone Brick isn't there. They should add it like the others no ?

Comment: @Warface From the image, it's currently missing, yes. The table in that article lists all blocks that have extra data with a D, and if you click it, it'll tell you what that extra data does. Also, the articles for the blocks themselves (e.g., [Cracked Stone Brick](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Cracked_Stone_Brick)) list the ID correctly, with damage value.

Comment: There's also a glitch that lets you create these blocks out of stone brick stairs. See [What's the difference between these stone brick blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30468/3454)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Data Values]

98:0 for the stone bricks, 98:1 for mossy and 98:2 for cracked, where the number after the colon is the 'damage' value. Other blocks that have different types such as leaves and half-blocks work this way too.

Comment: Yeah but it's not shown as the others with their damage value :S They should add it